# OpenJDK 1.8.0_202 with CentOS 7: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file:

Tags: java, centos, redhat

I'm using the latest OpenJDK release:

```
$ ./jdk/jre/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_202"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_202-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)
```

I'm getting the linkage error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/apps/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary$1.run(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.FontManagerNativeLibrary.<clinit>(FontManagerNativeLibrary.java:32)
    at sun.java2d.xr.XRSurfaceData.initXRSurfaceData(XRSurfaceData.java:85)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:137)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:132)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getSystemMnemonicKeyMask(SwingUtilities2.java:2020)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:1158)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.initComponentDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:431)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicLookAndFeel.getDefaults(BasicLookAndFeel.java:148)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel.getDefaults(MetalLookAndFeel.java:1577)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:539)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:579)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.initializeDefaultLAF(UIManager.java:1349)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(UIManager.java:1459)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(UIManager.java:1426)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1006)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.createGlassPane(JRootPane.java:546)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.<init>(JRootPane.java:366)
    at javax.swing.JApplet.createRootPane(JApplet.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JApplet.<init>(JApplet.java:149)
```

Tested with the following OSs:

- Red Hat 7.4
- CentoS 7.4
- CentOS 7.0

I'm guessing installing libpng12.x86_64 would make it work. But is this normal or is there an issue with the latest release of OpenJDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually an issue that's been reported and fixed post GA release. The AdoptOpenJDK team then re-released 8u202-b08.

https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/851

So there are multiple versions of jdk8u202-b08 out there. I downloaded a fresh release and it is working well without having to install libpng12.

I was told new versions will include a AdoptOpenJDK specific build number to be able to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

A compatibility package for libpng 1.2 is provided as part of the `libpng12` package.  You can install it as root using:

```
yum install libpng12
```

However, there might be additional integration issues with the AdoptOpenJDK builds.  If possible, you should use the OpenJDK build that is part of Red Hat Enterprise Linux.  This OpenJDK build comes with RPM dependency information and is linked against the current system libpng version (1.5.13).

You can likely install the OpenJDK RPMs from the current Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 version on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 (which is only covered by Extended Update Support at this point).  OpenJDK itself is not included in the [EUS package set](https://www.redhat.com/en/about/red-hat-enterprise-linux-extended-update-support-eus-package-inclusion-list).

Comment: How come this never happened with Oracle JDKs?

Comment: Presumably Oracle tested their builds on Red Hat Enterprise Linux before releasing them (or on Oracle Linux). They also bundled a *lot* of third-party code.